# Anyone know if Oracle/Sun publish the (junit) test classes they use for their java library classes?

Tags: java, junit, hashmap, hashcode

The reason I want to know is, after searching all over the shop for an implementation of LinkedHashMap/LinkedHashSet that allows you to specify your own equals/hashcode function, I couldn't find one.

I found a couple of libraries that implemented this just for HashMap, and one that was promising to implement it for LinkedHashMap at some point in the future, but still hasn't.

So I decided to just modify the HM source and do it myself, and then implement LHM after.

It'd be cool if I could just steal preexisting test classes for this code, and add to/modify them. Hence this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking for `Map` tests, you could do worse than [Guava's MapTestSuiteBuilder](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava-testlib/src/com/google/common/collect/testing/MapTestSuiteBuilder.java). You'll also find [SetTestSuiteBuilder](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava-testlib/src/com/google/common/collect/testing/SetTestSuiteBuilder.java) and other handy tools for testing collections [adjacent to it in the package](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/#git%2Fguava-testlib%2Fsrc%2Fcom%2Fgoogle%2Fcommon%2Fcollect%2Ftesting), as well as the ever-handy [EqualsTester](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava-testlib/src/com/google/common/testing/EqualsTester.java) [nearby](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/#git%2Fguava-testlib%2Fsrc%2Fcom%2Fgoogle%2Fcommon%2Ftesting). (See Louis's [link](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava-testlib/src/com/google/common/collect/testing/TestsForMapsInJavaUtil.java#132) for an example of how to use the test.)

You may also consider making a standard `LinkedHashMap` that happens to contain objects of Guava's [`Equivalence.Wrapper`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Equivalence.Wrapper.html) type. Basically, you create an [`Equivalence`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Equivalence.html) implementation containing an `equals` and `hashCode` method of your own design, and then use it to create lightweight wrappers for every object you care to keep in your set/map. The `equals` and `hashCode` on the wrapper will keep your `Set`/`Map` behaving the way you want it, and then you can unwrap the instances for use later.

(Naturally, you could also just skip Guava and write a single-field wrapper object that implements `equals` and `hashCode` too, but Guava has one already coded up for you.)

Comment: [Sample usage code](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava-testlib/src/com/google/common/collect/testing/TestsForMapsInJavaUtil.java#132).

Comment: Thanks, that looks like exactly what I need. I'll have to read over it a bit to figure out how to use it, but in general Guava stuff is always pretty well documented and sensible.

Implementing Custom LHM/HM/LHS/HS was actually surprisingly easy and I'm finished. I'd prefer that over having a map of wrapped objects just because it makes code look cleaner and I'd prefer to do it that way.

Comment: @fragorl You probably figured it out, but I forgot to put in that SetTestSuiteBuilder (and the rest of them) are adjacent to MapTestSuiteBuilder. I'm amending the answer anyway so it matches your question better.